# Appfabric cache (Velocity): Expiration in non-expirable cache and unreadable trace log?

Tags: caching, appfabric

we are using Appfabric cache in our project, and we ran into 2 major problems.

First - we are using named caches (no explicitly created regions). One of them, created as Expirable=false, Eviction=none, TTL=525600 is used for objects that should be always available (populated at application start, via the Put method). But from time to time (i couldnt identify exact timespan, nor connection to certain actions in application) all object in this cache suddenly expires - i can see this from performance counters - object count for this cache goes to 0, total expired objects counter increases of the amount of objects in this cache at the same time. Am i missing some other settings ? I tried both inserting them via Put() without timespan, and Put with timespan "a year". Still expires after several minutes...

The second problem - when I tried to solve first problem, i decided to use ETW trace logging feature to see in log, what is happening. I have created tracelog via logman and started it, waited for cache to expire, stopped the log, and have used tracerpt to create dumpfile from etl. Everything ok so far. But this dumpfile is useless, because there are no readable  data, only 4400690073007400720....... After some quick research, i figured out, that I need to supply an PDB or TMF file to tracerpt, so it can "decode" binaryeventdata to readable eventdata. Is it possible to get some of these for appfabric cache ? Or there is some other way to use ETW with appfabric to get some usefull readable log ?

Answer (score 2):

I found out what the problem is when your cache is expiring nearly instantly.
If your memory is low the cache gets cleared.

Check in the eventvwr -> Applicatin and Service -> Microsoft -> Windows - Application Server System Services and select Operational.

Look for warnings like:

Service available memory low - Cache private bytes percent {2} Cache working set percent {1} Cache data size percent {0} Available memory percent {21} CLR Generation2 count {2013} Released memory percent {0}.

Answer (score 0):

There is an explanation in here to convert log file to cvs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921010.aspx

But I can not even use tracelog tool.